# Hard drive always visible on desktop

Tags: finder, macos, icon, desktop

I have one HD named `Macintosh HD`.
I can’t tell when it happened, but since a few days my HD shows up on my desktop. I tried to disable it in the Finder settings, but it already is.
If I enable it I get a second icon for the same HD.

Does anyone have an idea how to fix this?

[image]

Comment: Both icons open Macintosh HD?

Comment: Oh, I forget to mention that. If I try to open the HD that is shown permanently, I get a message that I don’t have the needed privileges to access the hd.

Comment: And I just discovered that I can hide it if I disable external HDs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I solved it. A simple restart didn’t do the trick, but this is what worked for me:

1. Disconnect every external hard drive from my mac
2. Shut down the mac
3. Wait 10 seconds and start the mac